# Dynamic query usage whole streaming with google dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow pipeline that is set up to receive information(JSON) and transform it into a DTO and then insert it into my database. This works great for insert, but where I am running into issues is with handling delete records. With the information I am receiving there is a deleted tag in the JSON to specify when that record is actually being deleted. After some research/experimenting, I am at a loss as whether or not this is possible.

My question: Is there a way to dynamically choose(or change) what sql statement the pipeline is using, while streaming?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with Dataflow you need to think more in terms of water flowing through pipes than in terms of if-then-else coding.

You need to classify your records into INSERTs and DELETEs and route each set to a different sink that will do what you tell them to. You can use tags for that.

In [this pipeline design example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#a-single-transform-that-produces-multiple-outputs), instead of startsWithATag and startsWithBTag you can use tags for Insert and Delete.